# How to programatically apply portrait/landscape config changes if appropriate?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a FragmentActivity with 2 fragments, say fragment A and fragment B.

Fragment A has resource files for both landscape and portrait, B does not.
Both A and B contain data that is expensive to load. So (I think) I don't want the FragmentActivity to destroy and re-recate itself on configChange based on orientation.

In the interest of not reloading data, in the manifest I've added
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

but now when I rotate my device I don't get fragment A's landscape resource applied.

How can I best achieve that?

OR ... is it best to not add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the manifest, but override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the data with a Loader and remove the `configChanges` attr. The instance of the loader will survice the rotate and you can rebind the data into the new layout cheaply.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to support back to Gingerbread and looks like Loader is not available. Also, my loading is currently done by AsyncTasks and would be troublesome to refactor if there was a quick 'hack'.